# Swagger validation error when API uses enum

Tags: api, swagger, azure-api-management, swashbuckle, json-schema-validator

I’ve have the following Swagger document (simplified version) with two parameters. TypeCode (a string) and Status (an enum). When I try to validate/import into Azure Api Management , I’m getting the following error

```
Parsing error(s): JSON is valid against no schemas from 'oneOf'. Path 'paths['/Bids'].get.parameters[1]', line 1, position 188.
```

Swagger document

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "/my-api",
    "description": "My API",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/Bids": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Bids"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "query",
            "name": "typeCode",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "in": "query",
            "name": "status"
          }

        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
      }
    }   

  },
  "definitions": {
    "MyApi.ApplicationCore.Filter.Status": {
      "enum": [
        "Submitted",
        "Created",
        "Cancelled",
        "Accepted"
      ],
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Im not sure whats causing this error. i suspect is to do with the enum

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because the `status` parameter is missing the `type` attribute. Since you say this parameter is supposed to be an enum, it also needs the `enum` attribute containing a list of values. Even though the enum is defined in the `MyApi.ApplicationCore.Filter.Status` schema, query parameters in OpenAPI 2.0 cannot `$ref` schemas, so the `enum` must be defined in the `status` parameter directly.

Correct version:

```json
"parameters": [
  ...

  {
    "in": "query",
    "name": "status",
    "type": "string",
    "enum": [
      "Submitted",
      "Created",
      "Cancelled",
      "Accepted"
    ]
  }
],
```

Comment: Thats that works prefectly fine. The swagger that was posted was auto generating (netcore 3.1). How do i get the enum defined in the "parameters" section as opose to the "definitions" (as mentioned in the solution)?

Comment: Swashbuckle might have annotations or configuration options to generate inline enums. I'm not familiar with Swashbuckle though. Try [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=swashbuckle).